# Chai-spies: expect().to.have.been.called() is failing on local methods

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I'm trying to test some code written in Typescript and my test cases are failing.  I've simplified the code a bit to break down my issue.  I'm new to ts/js so most likely I'm just missing something obvious..

I don't have any classes defined in the traditional sense where you can create a new object. I just have two typescript files, which have functions defined.  For some reason my test fails when the function I'm expecting to be called is local to the function I'm calling.

Below are there two differing examples and their results.

My caller function `callFoo()` is in my `moduleUnderTest` file.  When `callFoo()` calls `foo()` in another file, my test case will pass.

**moduleUnderTest file** (where `foo()` comes from the helper file)

```
import { foo } from "path/to/helper/methods";

export function callFoo() {
    foo();
}
```

**helper method**

```
export function foo() {
    console.log("Foo was called");
}
```

and here is my test code

```
import { callFoo } from "path/to/module/under/test";
import * as helperMethods from "path/to/helper/methods";

chai.use(spies);
const expect = chai.expect;

suite("Testing Foo", () => {

    test("foo", async () => {
        const spy = chai.spy.on(helperMethods, "foo");
        await callFoo();
        expect(spy).to.have.been.called();
    });

});
```

**Output** (success)

[image]

However if I move `foo()` into the same file `moduleUnderTest` and run the same exact test it fails.

```
export function callFoo() {
    foo();
}

export function foo() {
    console.log("local foo was called");
}
```

Test class

```
import { callFoo } from "path/to/module/under/test";
import *  as moduleUnderTest from "path/to/module/under/test";

chai.use(spies);
const expect = chai.expect;

suite("Testing Foo", () => {

    test("foo", async () => {
        const spy = chai.spy.on(moduleUnderTest, "foo");
        await callFoo();
        expect(spy).to.have.been.called();
    });

});
```

Output (failure)

[image]
[image]

So you can see by the output the method was called

> local foo was called

but the `expect().to.have.been.called()` is failing.  Why is that? What am I missing?

Comment: First of all, it's perfectly fine and in fact desirable to keep your code simple and not use classes when simple functions will do. I expect the test framework doesn't realize it's the same function because it's a reference to a different object, the module namespace but that's just a guess. Regardless, I don't think you should write tests like that because it tests the implementation of the function which is pointless. You should be testing the interface of the function not how it gets its work done so you shouldn't care whether the helper was called.

Comment: thanks, I'm new to unit testing so you're probably on to something in that I'm not testing it right.  I thought the purpose of a unit test was to test it did what it's supposed to do? In this case I want to test the method callFoo() so wouldn't I want to validate it called the foo() function? Or what would I want to test instead, the output of the foo() function?

Comment: You're right, you want to test what the function does but that usually means testing that it Returns the correct value or produces the correct side effect, not how that happens. Looking at your test a little bit more, I think the conceptual issue here is that you're thinking of the module namespace object that you imported as the object under test and that's not correct. The function is the system under test. Consider that there are arbitrary numbers of ways that you could Alias and import and that function as well as multiple modules that could export the same function

Comment: If you are new to unit testing start with a simple testing framework like tape. You can always start using more robust or sophisticated Frameworks when you need to.

Comment: Sorry one more question related to nested functions to clarify.  Say I have function A that calls function B > which calls function C > which calls function D and function D is what outputs something at the end.  I just want to test the result of function D in that case? Because then I know that since function D has the expected result the upstream branches should be fine?  The reason I ask is because if just test function D and that works, then I figured I'd just verify function A ends up calling function D, so I'm not testing the same code twice, since I know my test for function D works

Comment: In general, that's the right idea. Typically function A would be combining the results of the functions it calls or modifying them in some way so it would still make sense to test A. Keep in mind testability increases dramatically when functions return values instead of causing side effects. It isn't always possible to write code in this way but the more of your code that you write as a transformation from inputs to outputs, parameters to return values, the more testable your system will become.

Comment: I think [this article](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/why-i-use-tape-instead-of-mocha-so-should-you-6aa105d8eaf4), while a few years old, is still very much on point in terms of testing JavaScript. I'm not as dogmatic as the author perhaps , but its definitely a good place to start https://medium.com/javascript-scene/why-i-use-tape-instead-of-mocha-so-should-you-6aa105d8eaf4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across an article which described my same issue.

Here is the article https://medium.com/@DavideRama/mock-spy-exported-functions-within-a-single-module-in-jest-cdf2b61af642

This issue has to do with the way the code is compiled.  If you're not using typescript and just using javascript I highly recommend reading the referenced article.

tdlr (solution for typescript);

1. Move the helper function (i.e. `foo()`) into its own module file

*OR*

2. Use an anonymous function:

From https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/936#issuecomment-532538300

Not working:

```
export function doSomething(a, b) {}
```

Working:

```
export const doSomething = function (a, b) {}
```

I should also note I'm using mocha and the GitHub issue I referenced provides some other solutions if using jest that may be more suitable.  In my case I chose to switch from a named function to an anonymous function.